# List Plans of all groups in my organization using Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: .net-core, office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-planner

I'm using Microsoft Graph SDK for .NET Core. I'm trying to get a list of all Office 365 plans in all Azure Active Directory groups within my organization.

I have been reading through a lot of questions, but haven't found a clear answer to my problem: As it's stated in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannergroup-list-plans?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), you cannot list plans in a group using client credentials (application permissions), which is the exact authentication method I'm using. Given this, how can I achieve my objective?

As per documentation, the only way to list plans in groups is to use *Delegated Permissions*, but in that case, and according to the [Microsoft Graph permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/graph/auth/auth-concepts#microsoft-graph-permissions):

> either the user or an administrator consents to the permissions that the app requests and **the app can act as the signed-in user** when making calls to Microsoft Graph.

If the signed-in user is a regular user then the application will only access the groups *that user* is a member of. Bear in mind that there may not be a single user that is a member of all groups.

Is there a way to get my application to list *all* plans in *all* groups within my organization?

Answer (score 0):

You can now use application permissions.

Outdated Reply:

> Planner currently does not support application permissions. Depending
> on what your scenario is, you have couple of options. One option is to
> create a user account to be used by your app, and add that user to all
> the groups. Then you'll be able to query the plans with the
> credentials of that user.

Comment: If you explain your scenario (e.g. is this a one time gathering of data?, is it periodic? Is it user/admin triggered?), I may be able to provide other options to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm developing a solution that will be deployed to our customers Office 365 environment and some of their members will be able to access a dashboard where an organization-wide plan overview will be presented.
Data in the dashboard has to be up to date so there will be a daemon or service that will periodically request from Graph the required information, including all group plans within the organization.